# How to work with nested Arrays and Objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, json, performance, linq

so im working on a small project where i am consuming and deserialising json string into objects on C#. i set myself a business logic where i want to search for a team and return the number of goals they have scored (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2014-15/en.1.json)

The issue is i want to return the number of goals using LINQ instead of a loop (my original method). However, i do not know how i can retrieve the score. e.g

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
class Program
{

    private static string jsonUrl { get; set; } = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2014-15/en.1.json";
    private static string teamKey { get; set; } = "swansea";
    static void Main()
    {
       var goal = Run(teamKey.ToLower());
       Console.WriteLine(goal);
       Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static int Run(string team)
    {

        using (var webclient = new WebClient())
        {

            var rawJson = webclient.DownloadString(jsonUrl);

            var jsonModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(rawJson);


            foreach (var rounds in jsonModel.rounds)
            {
                foreach (var match in rounds.matches)
                {
                    var goal = match.team1.key.Equals(teamKey) ? match.score1 : 0;

                    if (goal == 0)
                    {
                        goal = match.team2.key.Equals(teamKey) ? match.score2 : 0;
                    }
                    return goal;
                }
            }


            return 0;
        }

    }
}

public class Team1
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}

public class Team2
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}

public class Match
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public Team1 team1 { get; set; }
    public Team2 team2 { get; set; }
    public int score1 { get; set; }
    public int score2 { get; set; }
}

public class Round
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Match> matches { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Round> rounds { get; set; }
}

}
```

The code above successfully executes and returns the correct number of goals based on the football team. but i dont think for performance this is the best way. (input: "swansea" expected result: 2 , Actual result: 2)

the array is represented as follows:

```
"rounds": [
{
  "name": "Matchday 1",
"matches": [
    {
      "date": "2014-08-16",
      "team1": {
        "key": "manutd",
        "name": "Manchester United",
        "code": "MUN"
      },
      "team2": {
        "key": "swansea",
        "name": "Swansea",
        "code": "SWA"
      },
      "score1": 1,
      "score2": 2
    },
    {
      "date": "2014-08-16",
      "team1": {
        "key": "leicester",
        "name": "Leicester City",
        "code": "LEI"
      },
      "team2": {
        "key": "everton",
        "name": "Everton",
        "code": "EVE"
      },
      "score1": 3,
      "score2": 5
    }}]
```

Comment: Linq won't give you better performance.  You'll still have to touch all of that data to get your result.

Comment: In other news, that `return goal;` doesn't look right; it will return from the function on the first loop iteration, so I don't know how you're getting a meaningful result from it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Would you say this is the bests way? if there better way than this? thanks for any help.

Comment: I think, given this code is functional, that this question is more suited to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) as long as you provide a clear goal such as conciseness

Answer (score 0):

This seems to require the `from x in y ... select z` syntax to obtain readable LINQ. Replace the part that starts with `foreach (var rounds` and ends with `return 0;` by the following code:

```
return (from round in jsonModel.rounds
from match in round.matches
let goal = match.team1.key.Equals(teamKey) ? match.score1 : 0
select goal == 0 ? (match.team2.key.Equals(teamKey) ? match.score2 : 0) : goal).FirstOrDefault();
```

I kept this as similar to the code in the question, for clarity. It would be better to  extract helper methods to make the LINQ more readable: One helper for the expression `match.team1.key.Equals(teamKey) ? match.score1 : 0`, and one for the expression `goal == 0 ? (match.team2.key.Equals(teamKey) ? match.score2 : 0) : goal`.

The `from x in y ... select z` *can* be turned into a LINQ method chain. (E.g. the ReSharper tool can do that automatically.) But the result is so ugly there's no point in showing it.